# Using APEX to assemble HTML Letterhead Emails

Tags: apex, email-template

I am looking to assemble an HTML Letterhead Email Template for an email service integration project.

There are two sObjects that hold this information - `EmailTemplate` and `BrandTemplate`.

`BrandTemplate.value` = broken HTML (styles aren't associated to tags) Letterhead with CDATA tags throughout to hold the email Template info

`EmailTemplate.HTMLValue` = User-created HTML email template

I've been trying to merge the two (don't need to worry about merge fields / codes) with little success.

I have tried turning both into XML, navigating the BrandTemplate.value field, but Salesforce does not natively support CDATA.  I've also tried the polar opposite - stripping everything into text and doing replaces and substrings to assemble, but that also fails.

My end goal is to have a completed single HTML document consisting of both the BrandTemplate and EmailTemplate values.

Any hints / thoughts / clues?

Comment: How exactly does it fail?

Comment: There are two specific things that I'm running into issues with.  One - if you look at the structure of the BrandTemplate.value field, there are CDATA sections in three main areas - header, body, and footer.  Firstoff, I need to insert my EmailTemplate.HTMLValue into the body CDATA section.  Two - all of the styling and image tags are not properly formatted in the BrandTemplate.value field, so I need to go in and deal with that too.  If I had a full XML library that supported CDATA - not a prob, SF does not natively.

Comment: I've had some success in parsing / manipulating email templates using complicated regular expressions and String.replaceAll, does that offer a potential solution?

Comment: There are two major things that i'm having issues with with the replaceAll method - the styles are in their own tags and I need to merge them with the immediately preceding tag, and the image tags have CDATA outside the tag with the actual src value, so I have to get them in the previous tag as well.  All in all a major PITA.

Comment: I'd like to know how you managed to achieve this in the end.

Comment: Unfortunately in the end - there were many "ways" to get this done, but none of them were 100% reliable.  We ended up breaking up the content vs. template and sending to a 3rd party for assembly.

Answer (score 55):

**Salesforce hacking time:**
I had this exact requirement, and was stuck for a while because of the weird connection between EmailTemplate and BrandTemplate, and the inability to leverage a merging/parsing function however, I found a solution, this is far from a clean solution, but it seems to be working perfectly.

First what you will do is, create a single email message (like you would send it from apex):

```
// Here we will build the single email message
Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(1);
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
String[] toAddresses = new String[]{'invalid@emailaddr.es'};
mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
mail.setUseSignature(false);
mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
mail.setSenderDisplayName('MMPT');
mail.setTargetObjectId(UserInfo.getUserId());
mail.setTemplateId(sendTemplate.Id);
```

What we will do next is trick salesforce in sending the single email message, by setting a savepoint, sending the message and rolling back. The single email will not be send because of the rollback.

```
Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail});
Database.rollback(sp);
```

But now the beauty comes, because we triggered the sendEmail method, the email template got merged with the brandtemplate and the parsing took place. And you can find the parsed versions of your template components in the next variables (Subject, Text and HTML)

```
String mailTextBody = mail.getPlainTextBody();
String mailHtmlBody = mail.getHTMLBody();
String mailSubject = mail.getSubject();
```

This is far from what salesforce meant to do with single email message, and since we cannot leverage the platform parsing and merging functions, this did gave me a solution to this problem unfortunately through some hacking.

Comment: This trick is not working in for loop as i am trying to send 100 mails at a time using third party email sending api

Comment: I am getting the bellow error when i call this from batch apex "you have uncommitted work pending. please commit or rollback before calling out salesforce"

Comment: That error message has nothing to do with this way of hacking your templates together, it is because you do a DML statement (insert, update, upsert, delete) BEFORE doing a callout. All DML statements must be done after the callout

Comment: Hi @PJC, Actually i am using this one in batch apex calling the API callout by making for loop and i tried with making batch size as 1 but again I am getting same issue. is not it posible to place this logic in batch apex?

Comment: The solution I provide doesn't do any webservice callouts. My guess is that you do a webservice callout after doing the solution provided above, because I think that setting a database.savepoint or doing a rollback are considered DML statements

Comment: Awesome idea. Never thought something like that is possible. Looks like this is the only possible solution for an template with letterhead.

Comment: I was just looking around for how to do this, and holy crap, this is an inspired solution! Hat off to you :)

Comment: I don't think this works anymore.  The mail.getHtmlBody() returns null for me after going through this process.

Comment: Perhaps you are sending a text email, or using a html template with only a text version? IF that still doesn't work, try setting your API version back to 30 or something.

Comment: I am using a VF template - would that be the cause?

Comment: Could be, I haven't tested this with VF email templates, however, it is perfectly valid that a html value is null, when it's just empty. surely you have something in the textvalue? Or perhaps something is wrong with your template?

Comment: without seting whatId, how it will get merge field value ?

Comment: anyhow your hack and solution saved my day.

Comment: @pjcarly but the returned htmlBody will not contain merge fields

Answer (score 54):

[Summer 16 introduces two new methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.202.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_messaging.htm?search_text=RenderEmailTemplateBodyResult) that (finally) eliminate the clever hack by @pjcarly:

**For VF, HTML, and Plain Text templates:**

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = 
            Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(templateId, whoId, whatId);
```

**To get just the merged results from the templateBody (and any errors)**

```
List<Messaging.RenderEmailTemplateBodyResult> resList = 
        Messaging.renderEmailTemplate(String whoId, String whatId, List<String> bodies)
```

where `bodies` is a list of strings corresponding to the value of `EmailTemplate.body` as queried from the database

```
for (EmailTemplate et: [select Body from EmailTemplate where DeveloperName IN ('foo','bar')])
  bodies.add(et.Body);
```

Comment: I think your answer needs to be updated as your select statement for bodies returns a list of emailtemplates that need to be iterated through so that you can add the body field to a list of strings.

Comment: @techbusinessman - sheesh, no kidding, fixed, Thanks!

Comment: This is definitely the way to go now and should be marked as the correct answer

Answer (score 6):

When accessing templates and needing multiple objects I will
 -  select the template from the database
 -  define a merge syntax, use regular expressions "{!([A-z_]+)}" to get a key name
 -  pass a map of data to replace the key (if exists) with data

you now have a template which is just a string. you can push the template to a VF page with 
or send an email manually in code.

code example:

```
public static Map<String,String> merge_template(Map<String,String> obj, EmailTemplate email){
    Map<String,String> data = new Map<String,String>();
    String html = email.HtmlValue;
    if(html!=null){
        html = m(html,obj,Pattern.compile('(\\{![A-Za-z_]+\\})').matcher(html));
        data.put('HtmlValue',html);
    }
    else{
        data.put('HtmlValue','');
    }
    String body = email.Body;
    String subject = email.Subject;
    body = m(body,obj,Pattern.compile('(\\{![A-Za-z_]+\\})').matcher(body));

    data.put('Body',body);

    return data;

}
private static String m(String body,Map<String,String> obj,Matcher m){
    while(m.find()){
      String merge_field = m.group(0);
      String field = merge_field.substring(1,merge_field.length()-1);
      String value;
      try{
        value = (String) obj.get(field);
      }
     catch(Exception e){
        value='';
     }
     if(value!=null){
        body = body.replace(merge_field,value);
     }
     else{
        body = body.replace(merge_field,'');
     }
    }
    return body;
}

public static Map<String,String> build(String template,Map<String,String> data){
    EmailTemplate[] tpls = [SELECT HtmlValue,Body,Subject FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName = :template];
    if(tpls.isEmpty() == true){
        return "";
    }
    return merge_template(data,tpls.get(0);
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of this?

Comment: That's pretty cool ebt - let me pop around and let you know what I putter out.  Thanks!

Comment: Hello, That looks great - it's exactly what I was looking for. Could you please explain to me what UtilsList.getFirst does? I get the error "Save Error: Variable does not exist:UtilsList". Thanks in advance.

Comment: I used getFirst to cut down on the boilerplate conversion from a List to single object, but it turned out to be ill conceived. I updated the code to remove that reference.

Comment: Given code does not work for me; first it does not even compile due to  <code>return "";</code> where Map<String,String>  value is expected, not a string.
Also "{!([A-z_]+)}" regex does not work for me at all because it does not contain a dot and usually everybody has merge field like {!Custom_Object__c.Custom_Field_1__c}

Answer (score 2):

try to user the ***setTemplateId*** field of Mail.

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
EmailTemplate et=[SELECT id,name, subject,HtmlValue FROM EmailTemplate where name='xyz'];
mail.setTemplateId(et.id);
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
```

No need to do any custom parsing.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create a VF Email Template, and embed a VF Component within it to query those sObjects with an Apex controller.

Comment: That is correct, which I have done.  However - the merging of those two values from the two sObjects is the problem.  In your org, look at the values in those two fields and that's what I'm trying to merge together.  Getting it to display in a Component isn't the question.  =)

Answer (score 1):

I had some other idea to do this.

```
EmailTemplate template = [
SELECT Id, Name, Subject, Body, HtmlValue
FROM EmailTemplate
WHERE Name = 'My Name'];
templateId = template.Id;

Custom_Object__c obj = [
SELECT Name, Custom_Field_1__c, Custom_Field_2__c
FROM Custom_Object__c
WHERE Id = :my.Id];

Map<String, String> data = new Map<String, String>();
for(String key:new List<String> {'Name', 'Custom_Field_1__c', 'Custom_Field_2__c' })
{
    data.put('{!Custom_Object__c.' + key + '}', (String) obj.get(key) );
    System.debug( LoggingLevel.ERROR,'@@@ key : ' + key );     
    System.debug( LoggingLevel.ERROR,'@@@ obj.get(key) : ' + obj.get(key) );   

}
data.put('User.FirstName',UserInfo.getFirstName());
data.put('User.LastName',UserInfo.getLastName());
String body = template.HtmlValue;
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR,body);
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR,'@@@  template.HtmlValue: ' +  template.HtmlValue );
System.debug( LoggingLevel.ERROR,'@@@   template.Subject: ' +   template.Subject );

String subj = template.Subject;
for(String key:data.keySet())
{
    body = body.replace(key, data.get(key));
    subj = subj.replace(key, data.get(key));
}
```

Unfortunately it does not for email templates with letter heads.