# System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_FIELD_WHEN_USING_TEMPLATE

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am getting error

> System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0;
>   first error: INVALID_FIELD_WHEN_USING_TEMPLATE, When a template is
>   specified the plain text body, html body, subject and charset may not
>   be specified : []

when trying to send mail using the following code

**Function**

```
   public void sendMail(){
       String pickedReceipents;
       String pickedJobs;
       Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
       for(selectedRecord c : selectedContactValues){
           mail.setTargetObjectId(c.thisContact.id);       
           mail.setTemplateId('00X90000000keyP');
           mail.setBccSender(false);    
           mail.setUseSignature(false);    
           mail.setReplyTo('recruiting@acme.com');    
           mail.setSenderDisplayName('HR Recruiting');    
           mail.setSaveAsActivity(false); 
           Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail }); 
       }      
   }
```

In my system.debug I am able to print the contact ID

**09:03:50.032 (32022436)|USER_DEBUG|[183]|DEBUG|......................0039000000MwJzYAAV**

**Updated Code**

```
   /*Send email function*/
   public void sendMail(){
       String pickedReceipents;
       String pickedJobs;
       EmailTemplate emailTemplate = [select Id, Subject, HtmlValue, Body from EmailTemplate where Id =: '00X90000000keyP'];
       String subject = emailTemplate.Subject;
       String htmlBody = emailTemplate.HtmlValue;
       String plainBody = emailTemplate.Body;

       Messaging.Singleemailmessage email = new Messaging.Singleemailmessage();
       email.setReplyTo('recruiting@acme.com');
       email.setSenderDisplayName('HR Recruiting');
       email.setSaveAsActivity(true);
       email.setSubject(subject);
       email.setHtmlBody(htmlBody);
       email.setPlainTextBody(plainBody);
       for(selectedRecord c : selectedContactValues){
           email.setTargetObjectId(c.thisContact.ID);
           Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailmessage[] {email});
       }
   }
```

Comment: c.thisContact.id - is a contact ID .. Could that be causing a problem ..In that case what I need to add as setTargetObjectId ?

Comment: I have replaced mail.setTargetObjectId(c.thisContact.id); with mail.setTargetObjectId(c.thisContact.email);   and now I am getting a different error --- System.StringException: Invalid id: shruti0wadia@gmail.com

Comment: Can you change your email template to HTML ?I think that should resolve this

Comment: Hi @Mohit - I have changed it to HTML template .. still getting the same error                                                                                        **System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_FIELD_WHEN_USING_TEMPLATE, When a template is specified the plain text body, html body, subject and charset may not be specified : []**

Comment: Can you keep it very simple and see   for(selectedRecord c : selectedContactValues){
           mail.setTargetObjectId(c.thisContact.id);       
           mail.setTemplateId('00X90000000keyP'); 
           Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail }); 
       }

Comment: something like above try it

Comment: Yes, I have tried this also .. I found it [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_To_Email_Services_on_Force.com) earlier.. but it said I cant add list to mail.setTargetObjectId

Comment: I am getting [this](http://snag.gy/knwRP.jpg) error now after trying your code

Comment: I am trying implementing [this](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1242/passing-custom-string-into-a-salesforce-email-template) answer now :(

Comment: I am able to get email now.. Please check the updated code in question... But it gives me **Congratulations!
This is your new Visualforce Email Template.**  message in my email

Comment: Try to use setToAddresses also in the above email method

Answer (score 1):

I checked your error message. The original issue is that you can not specify html body when the plain text body is used. Please remve this line: email.setHtmlBody(htmlBody);

Comment: That is completely incorrect. `htmlBody` and `plainTextBody` are valid to specify together, and in fact they *should* both be specified when either is specified.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I believe Allen is trying to say that they shouldn't be set when a templateID is also been set. Is that incorrect ?

Comment: Maybe that's what he's trying to say. It's not what he says though. It would be correct. @SamuelDeRycke

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it seems that you cannot assign updated subject or body detail if email template id is assigned while sending email through apex code.