# Render a Salesforce Email Template in a Visualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template

I need to be able to load and render an email template in a visualforce page. What are my options here?

I understand that loading it is as simple as querying the EmailTemplate table. Now how do I render it in my visualforce page so the letterhead appears, etc?

Comment: Summer 16 resolves this  here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/120098/2602

Answer (score 4):

Your somewhat limited in your ability to render the template with any of the built-in Visualforce components, for one there isn't a way to get 'Merge Fields' to render the accompanied values.

With that in mind, I think the safest way to do it would be to create a frame and render the `EmailTemplate.HtmlValue` ([EmailTemplate](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_emailtemplate.htm)) as un-escaped HTML once you have queried the template in your VF Controller (probably would query the template by name)

Comment: Hey thanks! Is there anything special I need to do about the `<![CDATA[]]>` markups contained in `EmailTemplate.HTMLValue`?

Answer (score 0):

you can get Merge Fields from email Template..

```
 
for(EmailTemplate templ : selectedTemplateList) 
{
```

Organization org = [SELECT id, Name FROM Organization];
                            Id orgId = org.Id;
                            String Name = org.Name;

```
      templ.Body = templ.Body.replace('{!Organization.Name}',org.Name); 

            this.emailTemp.body = templ.Body.replace('\n','<br>') ;
            this.emailTemp.htmlValue =  templ.Body.replace('\n','<br>') ;
            this.emailBody = templ.Body; 
            this.emailSubject = templ.Subject; 
break;
```

}