# How to get Email Template executed body

Tags: apex, api, email-template, apex-email-service

I am working on sending email by using 3rd party application like Amazon SES

When i query for perticular email template i am getting body whaever the email templated had

like 
Email Template body
Hello {!case.name}

I am retriving only above body not like executed body
Hello CaseName(records name).

As i got sence like without using case id how can it get name.

But i am wondering that how i  need to send case id dynamically and how i can get executed body

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you please explain a bit more on what you are trying to do, I am at least having a very hard time following what you are asking for.

Answer (score 3):

I did something similar for previewing an email before it's being sent. The idea is to set up two emails in a list, one correctly and the other one not, try and send them and retrieve the generated email body in the catch statement:

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] previewEmails = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{};
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage firstPreviewEmail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
firstPreviewEmail.setUseSignature(false);
firstPreviewEmail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
firstPreviewEmail.setTemplateId(templateId);
firstPreviewEmail.setTargetObjectId(UserInfo.getUserId());
firstPreviewEmail.setWhatId(dealId);
previewEmails.add(firstPreviewEmail);
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage secondPreviewEmail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
previewEmails.add(secondPreviewEmail);
try {
    List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> previewResult = Messaging.sendEmail(previewEmails);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    generatedEmailBody = firstPreviewEmail.getHtmlBody();  // Email body generated
}
```

Comment: you might want to annotate the code a bit to indicate why the `secondPreviewEmail` is invalid. Good hack

Comment: Summer 16 resolves this hack here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/120098/2602

Comment: This post made me laugh ... very smart hack :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think this question has been asked many times ...how to get the rendered email template and save/use it somewhere.

And the answer is found here through a rather clever hack -- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/8745/2602

Involves constructing the email and then doing a rollback to get the rendered value.

Comment: Hi @crop1645, i followed the above link, i am using the code in for loop as i mentioned earlier sending more email, i am getting error like "you have uncommitted work pending. please commit or rollback before calling out salesforce" , where i am doing wrong

Comment: Sunny, without knowing more details -- and I think you should post a new question to deal with this issue, you should look at items like this: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003701&language=en_US as well as Google `you have uncommitted work pending. please commit or rollback before calling out` as this error relates to callouts and dml

Comment: Hi @crop1645, I am using batch apex to send email to contacts using amazon ses, there i am using the above process to get email template body and send to contact. There i am making for loop to send multiple emails, and i even tried with making batch size as 1, still i am getting error as "you have uncommitted work pending. please commit or rollback before calling out"

Comment: Sunny - please post as a new question on SFSE your issue with uncommitted work pending - you'll need to post your code as well (stripped down to the essentials to avoid code dumping on us)

Comment: Hi @corp1645, i posted my issue with code, can you please look into it and suggest me where i am doing wrong,http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/53191/using-batch-apex-to-generate-dynamically-merge-field-values