# Using Batch APEX to generate template body dynamically with merge field values

Tags: apex, batch, webservices, http

I am using Amazon SES to send mails to the all opportunities using batch apex with the body of email template. I'm using the solution proposed in an answer to [Using APEX to assemble HTML Letterhead Emails](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/8745/3263). Basically i'm fencing the `Messaging.sendEmail()` between a savepoint and rollback in order to get the template applied.

Here is the code

```
Global class Class1 implements
    Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.AllowsCallouts{

    Global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        String query = 'SELECT Id,name,accountid,contactid__c,email__c from opportunity';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    Global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Opportunity> Scope) {
        for(Opportunity oop:scope){
            list<string> toAddresses = new list<string>();
            toAddresses.add('sample@gmail.com');
```

Here i am using email technique with merge field values, there i am receiving complete body

```
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();     
    mail.setWhatId(oop.Id);     mail.settargetObjectId(opp.contactid__c);
    mail.setTemplateId(tempbody); 
    mail.setToAddresses( toAddresses);

    Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint(); 
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail }); 
    Database.rollback(sp);

    tempbody = mail.getPlainTextBody();
    httpReq.setEndpoint('https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com');
    [..]
```

Here i am calling http callout to send mail by using the Amazon SES

```
            httpReq.setBody(email);
            System.debug(httpReq.getBody());
            Http http = new Http();
            HttpResponse response = http.send(httpReq);        
        } 
    }   
}
```

Here i am getting error like , **You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out**

I feel that calling http callout and commit and rollback in same causing the issue.
Please suggest me where i am doing wrong, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats the purpose of your rollback? Also not sure why you're sending the email before building a body for it.

Roll back is a DML operation and you can't do DML and http calllouts in the same thread if there is anything uncommitted.

Comment: If we dont use rollback, mail will send using salesforce standard way that does not allow to send more mails per day as we had limitations, i am sending the mails by thirdpart, I.e.., Amazon SES

Comment: Why are you calling `Messaging.sendEmail()` at all, when you do not intend to send the e-mail using the salesforce infrastructure?

Comment: @AlexanderJohannes,  After placing the "Messaging.sendEmail()" this only i can able to get template body, else it is coming null

Comment: @Sunny Have you tried querying the template and manually parsing it instead then?

Comment: You mean to say replacing the field values by programatically, presently i am using the same, it is working fine. But it is taking more time to execute and i am wondering for standard salesforce way to handle this

Comment: Relying on some undocumented behaviour (`getPlainTextBody()` isn't even officially documented) does not look like the *official* way. I would also opt for some custom code to replace the tokens from the template.

Comment: Okay @AlexanderJohannes, please send some sample code to replace tokens from template if posible

Comment: This has been answered at the original question: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/220/3263. This platform is generally not ment to write code on your behalf. Please try it by yourself and ask a new question, if there are any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Although the error says to commit or rollback before making the callout, and you are doing the rollback, SFDC seems to ignore this when the callout is executed - this could be because of batch context but I didn't have time to explore that.

OK, here are some ways to work around the error

**Option 1**
You will need two batchable classes and one custom object `Deferred_Callouts__c`.

- Batchable class 1 - use the Database.savepoint - rollback sequence to get the rendered template. Then save the email recipient id and body in the custom object `Deferred_Callouts__c`.  insert these all in the finish() method - which then invokes Batchable class 2
- Batchable class 2 - Read all the Deferred_Callouts__c and construct the callouts

Considerations:

- You are limited in the [# of callouts](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm) so you'll need to be careful of limits in the batch size passed as `scope`.

**Option 2**
You will need one batchable class, one custom object `Deferred_Callouts__c`, and a workflow

- Batchable class 1 - use the Database.savepoint - rollback sequence to get the rendered template. Then save the email recipient id and body in the custom object `Deferred_Callouts__c`.  insert these all in the finish() method
- Use a workflow that executes upon Create of  `Deferred_Callouts__c` that uses an outbound message action to send via SOAP to the end point (assumes endpoint supports SOAP)

**Option 3**

You will need to use the [Dan Appleman Async Framework](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZqqiIg_mynY) as presented at [Dreamforce](http://advancedapex.com/dreamforce13/) that allows for unlimited async operations. This is well worth understanding.

This is my personal favorite as the solution is extensible to all your async needs over time

**Option 4**
Do what Alexander suggested and use the simulated merge field approach [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/220/3263) . If you have formulas in the template, this will be difficult. This avoids altogether the DML operations.

Comment: Hi @corp1645, I selected option 3, but i can not able to understand how to do that. Any suggestions to startup

Comment: Sunny -- I would suggest a) Purchasing Appleman's book  - Advanced Apex Programming, second edition which will explain in detail how to use the framework and includes code samples for download. The book was written after the Dreamforce links above and has some framework enhancements. Then, b) develop iteratively and make sure each bit is working before trying to debug it all at once

Comment: You can try by using @future
Global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Opportunity> Scope){
}

Answer (score 1):

Use `Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate` to generate the rendered `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage`.  Then use `getPlainTextBody()`, `getHtmlBody()`, etc. on the rendered message.

Answer (score 0):

There is one solution in which you can make use of Database.Stateful and send emails even avoiding uncommited work pending error.
Here is the code:

```
Global class Class1 implements
    Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.AllowsCallouts,Database.Stateful{ //Marking this batch as stateful in order to maintain tempates

    List<EmailMessageWrapper> emails = null;

    Global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        String query = 'SELECT Id,name,accountid,contactid__c,email__c from opportunity';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    Global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Opportunity> Scope) {
        //CALLOUT SAFE ZONE: since no DML PERFORMED
        if(emails!=null){
            //do your callouts and send mails
        }

        //CALLOUT UNSAFE ZONE: since DML would be performed
        //Prepare your emails ready when the execute would be executing
        emails = new List<EmailMessageWrapper>();
        /****
         * YOUR WORKAROUND CODE TO GET TEMPLATE VARIABLES POPULATED 
         * THIS WILL INCLUDE SAVEPOINT , sendEMAIL  & ROLLBACK
         * /
        /*****
         * NOTE : Now whatever you populate in emails will not be sent in the same context but 
         * these emails will be sent when next time execute would run. So you are preparing emails to be sent for next executes execution
         * where you would not face uncommited work pending since you wont be making any dmls before making callout.
         * when last opportunity (opportunities) would be considered then emails would be populated which would need to be sent from finish method.
         */

    }

    Global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        //do your callouts to send last batch of emails
    }

    //Wrapper class to hold email information
    class EmailMessageWrapper{
        String subject;
        String body;
        String toAddresses;
        String ccAddresses;
    }

}
```