# can setTemplateId be used along with SetHtmlBody for the following code?

Tags: email, email-template, apex-email-service, email2case, massemailmessage

```
public EmailMessageWrapper(String fromAddr, Id toAddrId, String sub, Map<String, String> mapSubjectParams, Map<String, String> mapBodyParams) {

    this(fromAddr, null, toAddrId, null, sub, mapSubjectParams, null, mapBodyParams );

}


public EmailMessageWrapper(String fromAddr, String toAddr, Id toAddrId, String bccAddr, String sub, Map<String, String>  mapSubjectParams, String body, Map<String, String> mapBodyParams) {

    this.FromAddress = fromAddr;

    this.ToAddress = toAddr;

    this.ToAddressId = toAddrId;

    this.BccAddress = bccAddr;

    this.Subject = sub;

    this.ParameterSubjectMap = mapSubjectParams;

    this.Body = body;
    this.ParameterBodyMap = mapBodyParams;

}
```

---

```
public static void sendEmail(List<EmailMessageWrapper> listEmailMessageWrapper, String emailTemplateName) {
    List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> listEmailResult = null;

    List<Messaging.Singleemailmessage> listSingleEmailMessages = new List<Messaging.Singleemailmessage>();

    EmailTemplate emailTemplate = [SELECT Id, Subject, HtmlValue, Body FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name = :emailTemplateName];

    for (EmailMessageWrapper emailMessageWrapper : listEmailMessageWrapper) {

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

        mail.setSenderDisplayName('Case Age Notification');

        if(emailMessageWrapper.FromAddress != null && emailMessageWrapper.FromAddress.length() > 0)

            mail.setReplyTo(emailMessageWrapper.FromAddress);

        if(emailMessageWrapper.ToAddress != null && emailMessageWrapper.ToAddress.length() > 0)

            mail.setToAddresses(new String[] { emailMessageWrapper.ToAddress });

        else
            mail.setTargetObjectId(emailMessageWrapper.ToAddressId);

        if(emailMessageWrapper.BccAddress != null && emailMessageWrapper.BccAddress.length() > 0)

            mail.setBccAddresses(new String[] {emailMessageWrapper.BccAddress });

        String subject = null;

        if(emailMessageWrapper.Subject != null && emailMessageWrapper.Subject.length() > 0) {

            mail.setSubject(emailMessageWrapper.Subject);

            subject = emailMessageWrapper.Subject;

        } 
        else
            subject = emailTemplate.Subject;

        for(String key: emailMessageWrapper.ParameterSubjectMap.keySet())

            subject = subject.replace(key, (emailMessageWrapper.ParameterSubjectMap.get(key) == null ? '' : emailMessageWrapper.ParameterSubjectMap.get(key)));

        mail.setSubject(subject);

        String htmlBody = emailTemplate.HtmlValue;

        String plainBody = emailTemplate.Body;

        for (String key : emailMessageWrapper.ParameterBodyMap.keySet()) {

            htmlBody = htmlBody.replace(key, (emailMessageWrapper.ParameterBodyMap.get(key) == null) ? '' : emailMessageWrapper.ParameterBodyMap.get(key));

            plainBody = plainBody.replace(key, (emailMessageWrapper.ParameterBodyMap.get(key) == null) ? '' : emailMessageWrapper.ParameterBodyMap.get(key));

        }

        mail.setHtmlBody(htmlBody);

        mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);

        mail.setPlainTextBody(plainBody);

        listSingleEmailMessages.add(mail);

    }

    if(!Test.isRunningTest())

        listEmailResult = Messaging.sendEmail(listSingleEmailMessages);

}
```

---

```
public static void processSchedules() {

    Integer slaTime = 3;

    List<EmailMessageWrapper> listEmailMessageWrapper = new List<EmailMessageWrapper>();

    String slaTimeLabel = 'Days';

    List<Case> listCases = [SELECT Id, CaseNumber, CreatedDate, OwnerId, Status FROM Case WHERE Status <> 'Closed'];

    for(Case c : listCases) {

        if(DateTime.now() > c.CreatedDate.addDays(slaTime)) {

            long numDays = (DateTime.now().getTime() / 1000 / 60 / 1440) - (c.CreatedDate.getTime() / 1000 / 60 / 1440);

            Map<String, String> mapSubjectParams = new Map<String, String> {

                    '{!Case.Status}' => c.Status,

                    '{!numDays}' => String.valueOf(numDays)

            };

            Map<String, String> mapBodyParams = new Map<String, String> {

                    '{!Case.CaseNumber}' => c.CaseNumber,

                    '{!Case.Status}' => c.Status,

                    '{!numDays}' => String.valueOf(numDays),

                    '{!Case.CreatedDate}' => c.CreatedDate.date().format(),

                    '{!slaTime}' => String.valueOf(slaTime),

                    '{!slaTimeLabel}' => slaTimeLabel

            };

          listEmailMessageWrapper.add(new EmailMessageWrapper('admin@salesforce.com', c.OwnerId, null, mapSubjectParams, mapBodyParams));

      }

  }

 if(listEmailMessageWrapper.size() > 0)

    UtilityClass.sendEmail(listEmailMessageWrapper, 'Case Aging Notification Email Template');

}
```

Comment: what happens when execute the code? Does it work or does it throw an exception?

Comment: When I execute it i got the email with the template specified in the htmlValue only  and the letterhead is not merged along with it. Somehow the brandtemplateId is unable to merge with my template

Comment: Just to reply your subject, TemplateId and setHTMLBody cannot be used in single mailing instance

Answer (score 0):

Check this thread:

[Using APEX to assemble HTML Letterhead Emails](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13/using-apex-to-assemble-html-letterhead-emails/120098#120098)

You might find your answer here!