# Preview email content of email templates before sending

Tags: apex, visualforce, email, email-template

I am developing a feature to send a email from a Custom Visualforce page. 
For this I am using the *Messaging.SingleEmailMessage* class.

I need to give users, the option to select email templates from a set of email templates in the Salesforce 'Email template'.

**However i cannot find a way to preview emails which will be sent**. My email templates will have data mapped from the respective record. How can i solve this problem of previewing the email templates with the values from email templates?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 4):

In short, there is no simple 'preview' function available to you. You could work around it using Visualforce pages/components for the preview. Assuming you are using Visualforce Email Templates, you could do something like this:

1. Copy the relevant content out of the Visualforce Email Template into
   a Visualforce Component
2. In your Email Template, reference the
   component e.g. `<c:EmailContent obj="{!relatedTo}"/>` to render the
   content
3. Create a new Visualforce page, also referencing the
   component (as #2)
4. Use the Visualforce page just created as a preview

If you wanted to show your user a list of Email templates to choose from, you could simply query the EmailTemplate object with some valid criteria, e.g.

```
Select Name from EmailTemplate Where IsActive = true
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand  the solution you suggested can be applied if there is a single template. But i will have a choice a email template which can be selected while sending. How can i handle that?

Comment: Modified answer...

Comment: @sagar I think your answer may still be here.  If you have multiple templates you want them to consider, the real question is how do I allow them to send the one they want.  If each template has it's own component for content, simply showing the component options (apex:tabPanel possibly or dropdown that causes a re-render) can be a relatively simple matter.  From there you just need to figure out how the user will select the one they want and build an action to send only the one they selected.

Comment: there is an alternative solution here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/8745/2602

Comment: wow, a super hack - very resourceful