# Getting VF Email Template Content in Apex

Tags: apex, vf-email-template

I have a VF email template and in apex I want to get it's content and will replace its merge fields. I am using below code but it gives null value.

```
EmailTemplate et = [select body,htmlvalue,templatetype from emailtemplate where id='00X60000004GK1SEAW'];
system.debug('body-'+et.Body); // gives me null
system.debug('html-'+et.htmlvalue); // gives me null
system.debug('html-'+et.templatetype); // gives me visualforce
```

Can anyone tell me how to get content of VF template here?

Comment: in order to get the content you need to set email messaging targetObjectId and setwhatId

Comment: @Ratan - I don't want to send any email. I just want to preview email content to the User. It works fine with HTML template but not with VF template.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest a workaround like this:

[Getting Email's Html body](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/8745/25920)

Here, in this link, @Pieterjan Carly, didn't send actual email. However he used a feature of Salesforce, when we use SEND method, it automatically creates Email Body.

**Now, Solution to your problem:**

1. Get EmailTemplate
2. Set merge fields
3. Send dummy mail and rollback it
4. As of now,you got exact body, store it in a STRING
5. Set that stored string on VF, so that you can show the EmailTemplate preview
   in VF