# How to get Visualforce Email template content in apex?

Tags: apex, vf-email-template

I have a requirement where i have to use Visual force Email template.so, i have created a vf email template.Now i want to get that vf email body in apex controller.i now if i use custom HTML template i can get body.but my requirement is VF email template.

```
EmailTemplate template = [Select id,HtmlValue,Body from EmailTemplate where name =:'testEmail' limit 1];  
system.debug('##template##'+template);
string hbody=template.HtmlValue;
system.debug('##hbody##'+hbody);
```

**Result**

> EmailTemplate:{Id=00Xf0000000M7mQEAS, HtmlValue=null, Body=null}
>   hbody null

Here am getting `null` values. Can any one please help me on this?

Comment: does this help? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/13/2602

Comment: Hi Cropredy,
Thanks for replay.with above link i can get body.But i want to replace merge fields which are present in vf page.can u help me .

Comment: Vishnu -- you're going to have to expand your question [edit] with more details as I'm afraid it is unclear

Answer (score 0):

The `Markup` field on the `EmailTemplate` object will give you the Visualforce markup, HTML, JavaScript, or any other Web-enabled code that defines the content of the template.

[Email Template Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_emailtemplate.htm)